# Kaddish DeRabonon after Pirkei Oveis in minyan

Tags: shabbat, torah-study, kaddish, minyan, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In our shul after Mincha on Shabbos we usually read Pirkei Oveis while there is minyan. But we do not read Kaddish DeRabonon after it, even if someone recited last line("Rabbi Chananya Ben Akashya...") loudly. So, maybe someone else also have this minhag of reading Pirkei Oveis while there is minyan and can answer me, why do not we read Kaddish after it?

Comment: Are there any mourners present? Sometimes non mourners are squeamish about reciting kaddish

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, mourner is present there.

Comment: Perhaps he is unaware that he is supposed to say it?

Comment: @GershonGold maybe, but it is strange that no-one didn't do it

Comment: I've heard two versions of this minhag. Do you say Pirkei Avos before or after Aleinu?